# Error al ejecutar mpirun en Xubuntu

Tags: c, ejecutar, xubuntu, mpi

Muy buenas,

estoy utilizando OpenMPI 3.1.3 en Xubuntu y cuando compilo con mpicc (sobre gcc 9.3.0) el ejecutable no funciona con las llamadas mpirun o mpiexec donde aparece un error por violación de segmento, si que funcionan los programas que se ejecutan fuera de mpirun o mpiexec.

Muestro ejemplo sencillo, con su salida por consola:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char  *argv[])
{
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    printf("Soy el proceso %d de %d.\n", rank, size);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Una vez compilado sin errores y al ejecutarse con `mpirun -n 5 Teoria.out` aparece el siguiente error por pantalla:

```
[PPXubuntu:06703] *** Process received signal ***
[PPXubuntu:06703] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[PPXubuntu:06703] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[PPXubuntu:06703] Failing at address: (nil)
[PPXubuntu:06703] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x46210)[0x7f7e70ff8210]
[PPXubuntu:06703] *** End of error message ***
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
```

Agradacería cualquier ayuda, muchas gracias. Atentamente

Comment: Hum, normalmente uno ve que esto pase cuando hacen un montón de non-blocking sends y agotan la memoria... pero este caso es mucho más simple :/

Comment: Ha sido usar una máquina virtual de una universidad, realizar la pequeña prueba para testear y...boom! No funciona!. Agradezco tu interés mostrado.

Comment: Cuánto tiene de RAM la VM?

Comment: 2GB pero ya que preguntas, probaré de ampliar la memoria asignada, gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Tampoco sé si [esto](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=troubleshooting#intel-12.1-compiler) sea de tu interés. Entendería uno que en tu universidad dejan disponible una VM que funciona pero pues... no sobra.

Comment: Comprobado, no funciona, no sé si la VM está alterada y por ello no funciona, seguiré buscando por la immensidad de Internet, muchas gracias